# Using database default values with Linq to SQL codewise

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008, dynamic-data

I am using Dynamic Data with linq to SQL and SQL Server 2008.

I have a GUID column that gets his value from the default value with newguid(). When I set IsDbGenerated to true in the designer it works like a charm.

But when I renew table this property is set back to false again. So I added it to the metadata. For some reason it's not being pickup, "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" is being inserted in database. The displayname and readonly change are being pick up.

What am I missing?

> [MetadataType(typeof(CMS_Data_HistoryMetadata))]
>       public partial class CMS_Data_History
>       {
>
> ```
> }
>
> [TableName("Content")]
> public class CMS_Data_HistoryMetadata
> {
>     [DisplayName("Pagina Title")]
>     public object pageTitleBar { get; set; }
>
>
>     [ReadOnly(true)]
>     [DisplayName("Versie")]
>     public object version_date { get; set; }
>
>     [ColumnAttribute(IsDbGenerated = true)]       
>     public object entity_id;
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by extending the partial insert en update class and check there if the guid is filled

> partial void
>   InsertCMS_Data_History(CMS_Data_History
>   instance)
>           {
>
> ```
>         if(instance.entity_id == Guid.Empty)
>         {
>             instance.entity_id = Guid.NewGuid();
>         }
>         this.ExecuteDynamicInsert(instance);
>
>     }
>
>     partial void UpdateCMS_Data_History(CMS_Data_History
> ```
>
> instance)
>           {
>               if (instance.version_date == DateTime.MinValue)
>               {
>                   instance.version_date = DateTime.Now;
>               }
>               this.ExecuteDynamicUpdate(instance);
>           }